# Linked List written in ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, linked-list

I'm preparing for a technical interview and will be asked to write the algorithm for a linked list in ruby. I understand linked lists completely, but have struggled writing the code. Can someone show me how this is done? I started it below..

```
class Node
  def initialize(item)
    @item = item
    @next = nil 
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post you attempt?

Comment: You can find example implementations on google.

Comment: If you understand linked lists completely, can you explain where you are having difficulty with the implementation? When someone tells me they know how something works, I ask them to prove it by providing a simple, working implementation. I guess that is what a technical exam is.

Comment: I know this question is ages old, but I wrote a blog post on the subject that future visitors may find useful/interesting https://medium.com/amiralles/mastering-data-structures-in-ruby-linked-lists-708347a30360

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost did it, really. I can give you very old-school, Lisp-like implementation, if you are brave enough to show it to your interviewer. In this approach, list is a pair (two elements touple), which first element contains the element, and second contains another pair, etc, etc. The last pair have `nil` as a second element. And here is the **whole implementation of the list in Ruby**:

```
class Pair
  attr_reader :car, :cdr
  def initialize(car, cdr=nil)
    @car = car
    @cdr = cdr
  end
end
```

To construct the list, just use a lot of parenthesis, like in old, good Lisp:

```
list = Pair.new(1, Pair.new(2, Pair.new(3)))
```

Now, the world is yours. You can do whatever you want with the list, using simple recursion. Here is an example of recursive `inspect`:

```
class Pair
  def inspect
    if cdr.nil?
      car.inspect
    else
      "#{car.inspect}, #{cdr.inspect}"
    end
  end
end

pry(main)> list = Pair.new(1, Pair.new(2, Pair.new(3)))
=> 1, 2, 3
```

As you mentioned in a comment, you want to search the list. Here is the code for this:

```
class Pair
  def find(index)
    find_ index, 0
  end
  def find_(index, i)
    if index == i
      car
    else
      cdr.find_ index, i+1
    end
  end
end

pry(main)> list.find 2
=> 3
```

Comment: I understand, but how can I reference each item separately in the first example using the Pair class? Say for example if I wanted to find out the cdr of the second car, how would I isolate that in the code after the class is defined?

Comment: Updated my answer with `find` method. Now all should be clear.

Comment: can I use the find method with the first example of the Pair class that you gave? 

Can you adjust your first answer and show me how you would implement that method into that class..

Comment: Of course you can. `find` is a method of the same `Pair` class. `Pair.new(1, Pair.new(2, Pair.new(3))).find(1)` will give you a second element..

Comment: Nice "lispie" implementation.

Answer (score 1):

This is the standard Church Encoding of Lists (and Booleans):

```
True   = ->(iff, _) { iff }
False  = ->(_, els) { els }

Pair   = ->(first, rest) { -> x { x.(first, rest) }}
First  = -> list { list.(True ) }
Rest   = -> list { list.(False) }

List   = Pair.(1, Pair.(2, nil))

First.(Rest.(List))
# => 2
```

It's not what you would actually write in Ruby, of course, but it is very simple and demonstrates an understanding of one of the most important principles of programming: code is data and data is code.

Here's a more realistic object-oriented encoding of lists:

```
class List
  include Enumerable

  def self.[](*els) els.reverse_each.inject(Empty, &:cons) end

  def cons(el) Pair[el, self] end

  def prepend(prefix)
    case
    when        empty? then prefix
    when prefix.empty? then self
    else prepend(prefix.rest).cons(prefix.first)
    end
  end

  def to_s; "List[#{map(&:to_s).join(', ')}]" end
  def inspect; "List[#{map(&:inspect).join(', ')}]" end

  def each; return enum_for(__method__) unless block_given? end

  class << Empty = new
    def empty?; true end
    alias_method :inspect, def to_s; 'Empty' end

    freeze
  end
  Empty.freeze

  class Pair < self
    def initialize(first, rest=Empty)
      self.first, self.rest = first, rest
      freeze
    end

    def empty?; false end

    def each(&blk)
      return super unless block_given?
      yield first
      rest.each(&blk)
    end

    private
    attr_writer :first, :rest

    protected
    attr_reader :first, :rest

    class << self; alias_method :[], :new end

    freeze
  end

  freeze
end
```

Note that there are absolutely no conditionals and no loops in the code. That is always a good sign for object-oriented code: polymorphic method calls are more powerful than conditionals anyway, oftentimes, there simply is no need for conditionals.

Some examples:

```
list1 = List::Pair[1, List::Pair[2, List::Pair[3, List::Empty]]]
# => List[1, 2, 3]

list2 = List::Empty.cons(6).cons(5).cons(4)
# => List[4, 5, 6]

list3 = List[7, 8, 9]
# => List[7, 8, 9]

list4 = list3.prepend(list2).prepend(list1)
# => List[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

list4.partition(&:odd?)
# => [[1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 4, 6, 8]]
```

Unfortunately, this object-oriented encoding will blow the stack for larger lists (on my system `List[*(1..9338)].each {}` still works, but `9339` doesn't), even though `each` is tail-calling itself and thus *should* run in O(1) stack space. As Guy L. Steele pointed out multiple times, OO languages *must* support proper tail calls, otherwise you are required to break OO in order to avoid blowing the stack. (`prepend` is not coded for tail-calls, but it can be rewritten that way.)